# Sliding between recyclerview items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, slide, bottomnavigationview

I need to make something like this
[image]

And when I slide or select third option or first the view should become like this
[image]

I tried using linear layout and when I slided I added margins at runtime, but it did not seem good, can some please suggest me some good idea for achieving this?

Comment: Did you try scaleX and scaleY?

Answer (score 0):

If you want implement it by someting like LinearLayout and ImageView, you can change margin or padding of ImageView.
But there are some useful library for that reason.

Like this:
[image]
You can find it here:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Bottom-Navigation-Views

In addition you can find some other third-party libraries here:
https://camposha.info/android-examples/android-bottom-navigation-libraries/

I hope these be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case it is better to use `ViewPager` and add ‍‍`Transformer` for resizing and animate selected items.
Here is my `ViewPager` sample:

In your `xml` file:

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                visibility="@{!loading}"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingStart="40dp"
                android:paddingEnd="40dp" />
```

Here is your `fragment/activity` for config `ViewPager`:

```
binding.viewPager.apply {
            offscreenPageLimit = 100
            val transformer = CompositePageTransformer()
            transformer.addTransformer(MarginPageTransformer(PixelUtil.dpToPx(20f)))
            transformer.addTransformer { page, position ->
                run {
                    val r = 1 - abs(position)
                    page.scaleY = 0.85f + r * 0.15f
                }
            }
            setPageTransformer(transformer)

            registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback(){
                override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                    viewModel.currentPosition.value = position
                    super.onPageSelected(position)
                }
            })
        }
```

And here is for set `Adapter` for `ViewPager`:

```
val simpleAdapter = ModelsListAdapter(models) { onClick() }
binding.viewPager.adapter = simpleAdapter
```

Adapter should be some thing like this:

```
class ModelsListAdapter(private val list: ArrayList<Model>,val itemClick:() -> (Unit))
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<ModelViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ModelViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ModelViewHolder(inflater, parent,itemClick)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ModelViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val movie: Model = list[position]
        holder.bind(movie)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

}
```